# como me hago con una calculadora de USD a BTC en ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

Como hago una calculadora que por ejemplo mientras escriba  100 USD el valor del BTC es de 7556 se divida y salga el valor en BTC que seria
100/7556=0,0132345156167284 como lo veo trato de sacar la variable en PHP para hacer el calculo y me encuentro con 2 problemas:

1) al escribir 1 o un solo digito numerico enseguida me sale el resultado y se congela no me sale nada mas que el valor de 1 BTC en Dolares y quiero es que salga el valor de dolares en BTC.

2) no logro estraer la variable valor USD en PHP.

necesito hacer esto para que si que yo este actualizando la web ella me infomrme al momento de escribir si ingresas 100 USD tu valor sera 0.000012 BTC pero si ingresas 7000 USD recibes 0.98000000 BTC

¿Como puedo solucionar esos dos inconvenientes?

```html
    <form action="#" method="POST">
        <input type="number" name="usd" id="usd" placeholder="usd" oninput="procesar()"><br/>

        <input type="number" name="btc" id="btc" placeholder="btc">
    </form>


<script>
    function procesar(){
        var usd = document.querySelector('#usd').value;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET','https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/',true);
        xhr.onload=function(){
            if(this.status==200){
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                
                var price_usd = response[0].price_usd;
                document.querySelector('#btc').value = price_usd;

            }
        }
        xhr.send();
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Pon tu código php porque si no no podremos ayudar.

Comment: dele en ejecutar hay esta completo amigo lo demas es el lienzo html nada en especial

Answer (score 0):

Te falta toda la lógica de negocio dentro de este if:

```
if(this.status==200){
    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    var price_usd = response[0].price_usd;
    document.querySelector('#btc').value = price_usd;

}
```

Ahí tienes que hacer tú los cálculos según lo que guardes en response[0].price_usd

Y no sé pro qué te refieres a php si no tienes nada de php en tu código

Comment: es que no entiendo mucho de json de hecho lo estoy comenzando a estudiar yo queria hacer algo como esto: que pondre abajo

Comment: json es una cosa, php otra.